# How to add third-party source files (recursively) not for building but just to view definitions in vscode with CMake?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

I am using vscode with CMake. I have built the OpenCV library. I can include the OpenCV headers and link the OpenCV libraries. The vscode .cpp extensions can go to declaration by using the compile_commands.json generated after CMake configuration for Intellisense. But how can I go to the definition of functions? What should I add in my CMakeLists.txt . What about:

```
file(GLOB OpenCV_Sources "D:\\\Include\\\opencv-3.4.9\\\modules" "*.cpp")
```

It does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

For Visual Studio Code, you have to modify the C/C++ Configurations to include the path to these external sources in order for Intellisense to find them.

1. Open the Visual Studio Code **Command Palette** (`CTRL + SHIFT + P`), and type "Edit Configurations".
2. Choose **C/C++: Edit Configurations (UI)**, scroll down to **Include Path**, and add the path to your external headers/sources on a separate line. (Note, use `**` to make the search recursive.)

   ```
   D:/Include/opencv-3.4.9/modules/**
   ```

If you prefer to edit the Visual Studio code JSON configuration file manually, here is the [`c_cpp_properties.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference#_configuration-properties) file reference, with the **includePath** documentation.

---

*For Visual Studio in general (not Visual Studio Code):*

You can pull external sources into Visual Studio so Intellisense can reference them by creating another CMake target. And yes, you can use [`file(GLOB ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#filesystem) to grab the list of sources to include, but then you must add the sources to a *target* so they are shown as a separate CMake target in your Visual Studio IDE.

To ensure the external sources are not *built*, you can use [`EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL.html) when creating the target. Try something like this:

```
file(GLOB OpenCV_Sources "D:/Include/opencv-3.4.9/modules/*.cpp")
add_library(OpenCV_ExternalSource EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL ${OpenCV_Sources})
```

Note, use the `GLOB_RECURSE` option with the `file()` command instead to *recursively* search the given directory for all `.cpp` files.

Comment: @李XDONG I updated my answer with a more relevant solution that is specific to Visual Studio code. Hope this helps!